# select rows based on meeting two conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I am struggling to filter/subset a dataframe that has samples from multiple months, years, days. I only want samples from between Nov 1 - April 10 regardless of year. I can't seem to figure out how to do this in R without filter some of the data I want. Example of my data:

```
df = data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15),
                month = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,6,1,4,4,12,11,11,12,6),
                dat = c(1,26,3,15,15,16,4,3,16,11,3,12,14,6,27))
```

Code I tried:

```
    all1a<-df[df$month %in% c(1,2,3,4,11,12), ]
aa1b<-subset(all1a, month!=4 & day <10)
```

This code is obviously wrong as it subsets any day less than 10 and keeps all the days <10 regardless of month. But I want all the rows with all the months/days except for the few that are in April but before the 10th.

What I want the output to be:

```
   ID month dat
1   1     1   1
2   2     2  26
3   3     3   3
4   4     4   2
8   8     1   3
11 11    12   3
12 12    11  12
13 13    11  14
14 14    12   6
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: In your example data, you dont have a situation where `month == 4` and `dat == 2`, but you do have that in your desired data - is this a typo, or could you clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df |>
  mutate(date = lubridate::make_date(2000,month,dat)) |>
  filter(date >= as.Date("2000-11-01") |
         date <= as.Date("2000-04-10"))
```

Result (looks like example data varies from what you used)

```
  ID month dat       date
1  1     1   1 2000-01-01
2  2     2  26 2000-02-26
3  3     3   3 2000-03-03
4  8     1   3 2000-01-03
5 11    12   3 2000-12-03
6 12    11  12 2000-11-12
7 13    11  14 2000-11-14
8 14    12   6 2000-12-06
```

Or:

```
df |>
  filter(month %in% c(1:4, 11:12),
         month!= 4 | dat <=10)
```

(We want only dates in those months, and either not April, or if it is April, only up to the 10th. If your specifications get any more complex, this approach gets complicated and it's simpler to use dates.)

Comment: `filter(!between(date, as.Date("2000-04-10"), as.Date("2000-11-01")))`?

Comment: Perfect thank you very much. the second suggestion was exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

That would be a solution based on your approach, assuming that you have a typo in your data:

```
df = data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15),
                month = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,6,1,4,4,12,11,11,12,6),
                day = c(1,26,3,2,15,16,4,3,16,11,3,12,14,6,27))
all1a<-df[df$month %in% c(1,2,3,4,11,12), ]

aa1b <- subset(all1a, (month == 4 & day < 10) | (month != 4))

aa1b

   ID month day
1   1     1   1
2   2     2  26
3   3     3   3
4   4     4   2
8   8     1   3
11 11    12   3
12 12    11  12
13 13    11  14
14 14    12   6
```